# Can I load a CSV into a stored procedure that inserts into multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, csv

OK, an example is often easier to follow, so here is my procedure:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE mysql.insertTables (_first_name varchar(30), _last_name varchar(45), _create_time timestamp, _update_time datetime,  _hashid int,
  _id_status bit(2), _id int, _criminal_status bit(1), _dob int, _stateid int, _stateid_status bit(1))
begin
  START TRANSACTION;

  INSERT INTO MYDB.person (`first_name`, `last_name`, `hashID`)
    VALUES (_first_name, _last_name, _hashid);

  INSERT INTO MYDB.id_crimes (`id`, `id_status`, `criminal_status`, `hashID`)
    VALUES (_id, _id_status, _criminal_status, LAST_INSERT_ID());

  INSERT INTO MYDB.dob_state (`stateID`, `stateID_status`, `dob`, `hashID`)
    VALUES (_stateid, _stateid_status, _dob, LAST_INSERT_ID());

  INSERT INTO MYDB.timestamps (`create_time`, `update_time`, `hashID`)
    VALUES (_create_time, _update_time, LAST_INSERT_ID());

  COMMIT;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Now, what I'd like to know is whether I can load a CSV file to populate the tables directly using that procedure. I've seen workarounds for how to load to a single table, but this is to multiple tables. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why "hashID" not "person_id", etc?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Batch normalization can be done -- see [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my thought:

1. Create a table with all the fields that exist in the csv file.
2. Create a trigger (After insert on the table created in step 1) that calls your procedure that you already have, or let the trigger itself insert `new` values to the corresponding tables.
3. Load the CSV file to the table you created in step 1
4. The other tables will be populated automatically (Nothing to do here)
5. Drop the table that you created in step 1

Comment: That is a good workaround, so I marked it as correct. I'd really like to know if there is a way to do it more directly. :)

Comment: @Lori Hi. Have you found a more direct way by now? Thanks and greetings.